# JavaScript array string compare

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

I created one function with JavaScript which compare two string and return the number of the same characters with the following logic:

> Char 1 = “aaabc” | Char 2 = “aakbc” ===> My function return 2
>
> Char 2 = “88835” | Char 2 = “888vbr” ===> My function return 3
>
> Char 1 = “A1234” | Char 2 = “B1234” ===>  My function return 0

The logic is that when the function find that the FIRST character of CHAR1 is DIFFERENT is NOT EQUAL than the FIRST character of CHAR2 the function stop the iteration and return 0, if not: the function continue until we find that the CHAR1(i) !== CHAR2(i).

I am using this function to compare between two array of string, T[i] and V[j]. For each value of T[i] I am browsing all V[j] and returning the row which is more similar that T[i] and if the function find same result, I will return the smallest value V[j].
This is the code that I used:

```js
function MyFunction(a, b) {
  var n = a.length,
    m = b.length;
  var v;
  var i = 1;
  var j = 1;

  if (a === b) {
    v = a.length;
  } else
  if (a.charCodeAt(0) !== b.charCodeAt(0)) {
    v = 0;
  } else {
    v = 1;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      if (a.charCodeAt(i) == b.charCodeAt(i)) {
        v++;
      } else {
        return v;
      }
    }
  }
  return v;
}

var t = ["350", "840", "35"],
  v = ["3506", "35077", "84"],
  i, j, f, l,
  max,
  result = [],
  row = [];

for (i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  max = MyFunction(v[0], t[i]);
  l = v[0].length;
  f = [
    [t[0]],
    [v[0]]
  ];
  for (j = 1; j < v.length; j++) {
    if (MyFunction(v[j], t[i]) > max) {
      max = MyFunction(v[j], t[i]);

      f = [
        [t[i]],
        [v[j]]
      ];
      l = v[j].length;
    } else {
      if (MyFunction(v[j], t[i]) == max && l > v[j].length) {
        max = MyFunction(v[j], t[i]);
        f = [
          [t[i]],
          [v[j]]
        ];
        l = v[j].length;

      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  }

  result.push(f);
  console.log(f);
}
```

My code have an issue, the result which I have is:

> [350][3506] (Correct value)
>
> [840][84] (Correct value)
>
> [350][3506] (Wrong value)

I don’t find a solution for this issue, my code don’t compare the value [35], the code is comparing the first value [350] (this is the issue).

Comment: "Wrong Value" is not enough information. What Value do you expect and what did you get as opposed to that?

Comment: I am supposed to get :
[35] [3506]

Comment: @Fildor he expects his function to give a result for every items in `t`, and "35" is missing, he gets double results for "350" instead

Comment: `function MyFunction(a,b) {for( var i=0, l=Math.min(a.length,b.length); i<l; i++) {if(a[i] !== b[i]) {return i;}} return l;}` Job done.

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, now I am reading it. Misinterpreted it as "the function gives wrong result for [350][3506]" ... thx

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Your function is smarter ans shorter and return a correct result, i used it, but i am still getting a wrong result (
["350"] ["3506"] instead of ["35"] ["3506"]). so the issue is on the seconde part of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop of the outer `for` you start with initialize `max` to `MyFunction(v[0], t[i])`, and then scan-compare all the elements in the array. but, in the 3rd case, the resault of this check larger than al the other, so all the comparison in this loop get `false` and the final resault is what you see.

you can solve it if you initialize `max = 0` and then loop over all indices from 0 (include).